# Attach one-step to ground level deck

Tags: framing, deck, stairs

I want to do something like this photo but I don't know how to attach the one-step platform thing:

[image]

I circled two areas that should be attached by nails (assuming 16d Common Nail). But the photo shows they are not attached on the right side.

My question is: how to property attach the lower stair like this case? Or should I just submerge it into concrete in some part?

Comment: When you finish this deck,  you'll have to post some photos to the site (maybe on chat).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't submerge anything, and ensure that all post holes are filled in concrete and sealed from any water. . With stairs and  raised floors eliminate any source of water to prevent wood rot. With the cost of materials these days  you can't afford a failure due to rot Anywhere!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.