# How to attach single step for deck where deck rim joist is not low enough to overlap step rim board

Tags: wood, deck, outdoor, structural, patio

Similar to [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/91794/attach-one-step-to-ground-level-deck').  I am trying to attach a single step to a deck located adjacent to a patio, a setup which looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to secure the step effectively.  Here are a few sub-optimal things I've considered:

(***Important Notes***:  There is very little space to fit a driver underneath the deck from behind; I cannot fit myself under there, so I would be doing it blindly at an awkward angle toward myself from the outside of the deck.  The deck structural lumber only very slightly overlaps the step structural lumber vertically -- if at all -- not enough to accurately fasten with a screw through the back.) :

1. Customize a Z-shaped bracket and fasten from behind to the deck structural lumber and through the deck fascia into the step structural lumber.  This would be exceedingly difficult due to the access limitations mentioned above.
2. Screw through the deck fascia to the step joist from behind.  Fascia is not meant to be structural, but possibly combined with other methods it could work fine.  This would be slightly easier to accomplish than #1.
3. Attach the step structural lumber to multiple pavers with L-shaped brackets using a masonry drill bit and masonry screws.  This is not ideal by itself due to the potential for lifting or moving the pavers, but with enough pavers (which are "glued" together with polymeric sand) and in combination with #2 this might work.

I'm not thrilled about any of these options.  Can anyone please offer some sound advice?

Comment: From the front can you clamp a couple of 2x6s or other lumber to the back of the rim joist extending down to the concrete and attach them with screws through the front? Use this as the structural piece to attach the step.

Comment: For 3 instead of l brackets can you just run a PT 2x4 or 2x6 layed flat on the inside of the step to tie multiple pavers together kinda like a base?

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason this need to be complicated, it can all be accomplished from the front side.

[Install your pavers properly](https://www.thisoldhouse.com/patios/21015530/how-to-install-pavers) at the proper height ( *this is critical as it doing the [yeoman's work](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yeoman's/yeoman%20work/service) here.* ) And know-one wants a wonky landing.

Construct your step on your workbench to the dimensions you need.

Install a 2x6 between the stringers ( the sides ) on the back side so it is flush with the back of the step unit and then attach your  fascia to that 2x6 backer.

Now you can just set your pre-built step unit on your paver, slide it into place so the  fascia is up against the deck rim joist and fasten it to the rim joist from the front.

Your plastic fascia could be a more a robust,thicker,stronger board, this is effectively a riser that is acting as as another rim joist.  If you can not find one of sufficient width then you could run  strong boards run vertically.

You could use construction adhesive or L brackets to secure the step to the paver for added stability if needed.

*There is more then one way to skin a cat*. You could also just build a traditional  stringer, (  two step ) Use simpson strongtie brackets or a board at the top between the stringers and screw through that to the rim joist.

Comment: OP indicated that the problem is that the rim joist doesn't extend down far enough to provide a structural support to fasten into. The fascia isn't structural.

Comment: @HoneyDo It could be if of sufficient size.  *It is not a 10 step run*. It is only one step and the whole thing is siting on a paver, the fascia is just keeping it attached to the deck not supporting significant, if any, weight.

Comment: Noted. Your suggestions are right on target. I'm just trying to give him something more solid to fasten into.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I should have noted that the deck is already built, fascia and all, which I am not going to remove for this addition.  I did the patio afterward and now I've decided to add the step whose style mirrors that of the patio.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment I would use clamps to attach one or more 2x6s or other structural piece to the back of the rim joist extending down to the pavers. You can attach it with screws through the front of the rim joist. That should give you something meaty to provide structural support to the step.

Answer (score 0):

I could see two good ways to do this.  You could make an open stringer with the top step at deck level, or make a closed stringer with the first step down as in your picture.  Either of these will simply attach to your rim / band joist the usual way. You will have to cut slots in the fascia where the stringers attach to the joist.

[image: open and closed stringers]

Laying out the stringers takes a little thought and planning but there are plenty of resources online.

I'd be using Simpson or other hardware to make a strong attachment to the deck, and to support the stairs if you make a closed stringer.

[image: staircase angle]